# Finding $\int^{2\pi}_0 \cos(n\theta - 2\sin\theta)d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been asked to prove that:

$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \cos(n\theta - 2\sin\theta)d\theta = 2\pi \sum^\infty_{r=0} \frac{(-1)^r}{r!(n+r)!}$$

I have also been given a hint, to consider the function $f(z) = \exp(z - z^{-1})$.

It looks to me like I'm supposed to integrate $\exp(z - z^{-1})$ on the unit circle path, since I see a $z^{-1}$ and this equals $\bar{z}$ when $z$ is on the unit circle.

It's not as simple as just $\int_C \exp(z - z^{-1}) \;dz$ since I am supposed to get an infinite sum and I can't work out where that comes from, since it looks to me like there's only 1 possible singularity of $f$, at $z=0$ but $f$ isn't unbounded near $0$ so this can't be a pole.

I would appreciate if someone helped me get started on this, I am completely lost.

Comment: First, write the integral as one over circle $|z| = 1$. Next, expand $e^{-z^{-1}}$ as a power series $z^{-1}$ and verify you can exchange the order of integration and sum (remember all $|z| = 1$ at this step). Finally evaluate individual integral (if you want, you can do that by expanding $e^{z}$ as a power series in this step and once again verify you can exchange the order of integration and sum).

Comment: $\exp (z - z^{-1})$ has an essential singularity at $0$. Note that your integral is [the real part of, but by parity and periodicity the imaginary part vanishes] $$\int_0^{2\pi} \exp(in\theta - 2i\sin \theta)\,d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{in\theta}\cdot e^{-2i\sin \theta}\,d\theta.$$ That might make it easier to see where the $\exp (z - z^{-1})$ comes from.

Comment: Right, so I guess that I have to calculate something like $\oint_C z^n \exp(z^{-1}-z) dz$, then the residue at 0 can be worked out by doing the Laurent expansion at 0. I think I can use the power series for $z^n\exp(z^{-1}-z)$, then just extract the $z^{-1}$ term by looking at the binomial coefficients, which is where I suppose the factorials come from. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this what you're looking for, but here's a solution. Don't want to contribute to the noise, so if it isn't useful I will delete it. A representation of the [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) function is

$$
J_{n}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}{\rm d}y\;\cos(n y - x\sin y)
$$

So, the integral you're trying to calculate is

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}{\rm d}\theta\;\cos(n\theta - 2\sin \theta) = 2\pi J_n(2) = 2\pi \sum_{r=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^r}{r!\Gamma(r + n + 1)}\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2r + n} = 2\pi\sum_{r=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^r}{r!(r + n)!}
$$